# Javascript doesn't work when navigating inside the site

Tags: ruby-on-rails-7

My script works if you go to the page via a direct link in the address
bar, but if you follow the link, say, in the menu, the page is loaded,
but the js code is not executed. I add my js-file into assets
but it didn't help.
Js file is located in app/assets/javascript/application.js.

```
`let center = [55.81863845116168,37.87356624320199];
function init() {
    let map = new ymaps.Map('yandex_map', {
    center: center,
    zoom: 17
});
let placemark = new ymaps.Placemark(center, {
    balloonContent: `
    <div class="balloon">
    <div><h3>Автосервис Cars feeling</h3></div>
    <div class="balloon__contacts">
    <h5><a href="tel:+79163849119">+79163849119</a></h5>
    </div>
    </div>
}, {
    iconLayout: 'default#image',
    iconImageHref: 'https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/3177/3177361.png',
    iconImageSize: [40, 40],
    iconImageOffset: [-19, -44]
});

    map.controls.remove('geolocationControl'); 
    map.controls.remove('searchControl'); 
    map.controls.remove('trafficControl'); 
    map.controls.remove('typeSelector'); 
    map.controls.remove('fullscreenControl'); 
    map.controls.remove('rulerControl');

    map.geoObjects.add(placemark);
    }
ymaps.ready(init);`
```

My view:

````
<div id="yandex_map" class="map">
</div>
```


Connected via javascript_importmap_tags
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added to my link data: {turbo: false} and it works